# How do you specify a new instance of a view and its view-model for a composition in durandal?

Tags: durandal

I need to compose a new view during a foreach loop and specify that the each composed view is a new isolated instance. When I try this durandal is re-using the same view-model (maybe even the same view) for each composition. When the composed view is told to go get some data all the composed views on the page are updated simultaneously. How do I tell durandal that each composed view should be a new instance?

Pseudo code:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <div><!-- row data and buttons goes here --></div>
    <!-- each composed view should be a stand-alone instance -->
    <div data-bind="compose: { model: $data.sampleDataModel, activate: true, cacheViews: false }"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What does the code for `items` and `sampleDataModel` look like? `sampleDataModel` should return a constructor.

Comment: That was it! I was using object literal notation to build the view-model per examples and after converting it to a constructor function it started working.